# telegram bot don't send mp3 file from xammp server in windows server

Tags: audio, telegram, telegram-bot

1. **My mp3 link is :** [1.mp3](http://panel.cafefars.com:8088/mp3/1.mp3)
2. **OS = Windows Server 2008 and run xammp server**
3. **My code is :**
   `https://api.telegram.org/bot_token/sendAudio?chat_id=@test&audio=http://panel.cafefars.com:8088/mp3/1.mp3`

**Error after run :**

> {"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: failed to get
> HTTP URL content"}

mp3 url is correct but telegram not download

thanks all

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly** you should encode your URL - by [this one](http://www.url-encode-decode.com/) for example.
**Secondly** you should check your URL because it doesn't work for me too, but this is works fine - http://beginenglish.ru/download/audio/5/f/7/4/8843aa965d.mp3.

You can test it by this request (don't forget to change bot_token and chat_id):

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot_token/sendAudio?chat_id=@chat_id&audio=http%3A%2F%2Fbeginenglish.ru%2Fdownload%2Faudio%2F5%2Ff%2F7%2F4%2F8843aa965d.mp3
```

Comment: my link is ok and working for me but telegram not access to link !

Answer (score 0):

**Wrong Filename!**

**The filename in URL shall be at least 4 digits** (*or mixed letter/digits*) **long**