# Can't upload audio to telegram Bad Request: failed to get HTTP URL content

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I have working url to mp3, and I am trying to send audio to Telegram by this url. It works from time to time, but most of time it gives error

```
"A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 400 
Bad Request. Response body:
[b'{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: failed to get HTTP 
URL content"}']"
```

And I can't understand why, because I've checked the size and type, everything is clear, I can't find no more limitations in documentation of Telegram API. Who knows what is the reason of error?

link to mp3 - http://data3.api.xn--41a.ws/vkp/cs9-5v4.userapi.com/p15/51bdb5ec5899ed.mp3

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44646057/4269118)

Comment: I have already checked it, it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Check the file extension and the correct MIME type, please.

For one example, according to [the telegram doc](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sending-files):

> In sendDocument, sending by URL will currently only work for GIF, PDF and ZIP files.

Answer (score -3):

Check file size.

> Provide Telegram with an HTTP URL for the file to be sent. Telegram
>   will download and send the file. 5 MB max size for photos and 20 MB
>   max for other types of content.
>
> Post the file using multipart/form-data in the usual way that files
>   are uploaded via the browser. 10 MB max size for photos, 50 MB for
>   other files.